# move turtle to a specific patch with xy coordinates netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for.
I have 10 turtles called "renards" created on patches with specific attributes. I would like to make them go towards a specific patch with xy coordinates 10 101.

Here is how I created the turtles :

```
to creerRenard
  create-Renards 10
  ask Renards
  [ move-to one-of patches with [ cimetary = 1 ]
    set size 6
    set color red
  ]
end
```

so they are where I want them to be at the start but I can't seem to make them go towards a target with coordinates (one move per tick). I looked into the move towards target example but couldnt find anything...

Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you look in the NetLogo dictionary, you will see that `move-to` jumps to the destination. What you want is a combination of `face` and `forward`. If this comment is insufficient to fix your problem, please provide more of the code. The snippet you have will not run and hence answers can't be tested as the `breed`, attribute variables and `tick` etc are all missing.

Comment: thank you this was actually really helpful !